# Append value to string

Tags: excel, vba

How do I stop overwriting my string "finalString" and appending to it instead. I want for each w in D(V) to be one string before going to next w.

```
I = 1
x = 1
For Each V In D.keys
   Ws.Cells(I, 4) = V
   I = I + 1
   For Each w In D(V)
      finalString = w
      Ws.Cells(x, 5) = finalString
   Next w
   x = x + 1
Next V

Stop
```

Comment: Do you need that `finalString` to be the real final (with all concatenated keys)? Or concatenation until the next key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `+=` that will append all values to the righ of the current finalString

**UPDATE:**
My mistake.  In VBA is different should be `finalString = finalString & w`

my apologies

Comment: This doesn't work in VBA. it should be `FinalString = FinalString & w`

Comment: Thank you @Damian. I cannot mark your answer as solution since it is a comment

Comment: Don't worry @lass9509, wait if skisharp edits his answer and mark this one as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try one single line of code:

```
Ws.Cells(x, 5) = Join(dict.Keys, "")
```

To retrieve all PARTIAL concatenated keys:

```
Dim arr as Variant, i as long
arr = dict.Keys
  k = dict.count - 1
  For i = UBound(arr) To 0 Step -1
    ReDim Preserve arr(k): k = k - 1
    Debug.Print Join(arr, "")
  Next i
```